# Flash error 1046

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I am new into as3, was following some tutorials and I made this code:

Class 1 (Enemy.as):

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    public class Enemy extends MovieClip 
    {
        public function Enemy() 
        {
            x = 100;
            y = 0;          
        }

        public function moveDownABit():void 
        {
            y = y + 3;
        }
    }
}
```

and in main Class (AvoiderGame.as) :

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    public class AvoiderGame extends MovieClip 
    {
        public var enemy:Enemy;

        public function AvoiderGame() 
        {
            enemy = new Enemy();
            addChild( enemy );
        }
    }
}
```

I Linked my Instant with it and all checked and working. also I added the main class to Classdocument of my fla file, though I am getting this error :

```
C:\Users\x\Documents\Flash\tuts\game1- avoider\Classes\AvoiderGame.as, Line 2   1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Enemy.
C:\Users\x\Documents\Flash\tuts\game1- avoider\Classes\AvoiderGame.as, Line 6   1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Enemy.
```

any ideas ?

Comment: Found the Solution :

name of Symbole on Stage cannot be same as Class name =s
Stupid Adobe...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your classes AvoiderGame and Enemy are in the same package(folder) and its file names are the same as class names (AvoiderGame.as & Enemy.as).

Comment: they are in same folder, and yes the class names are the same the the action script file names. Still Cant fix the error, I am using Adobe flash CS 5.5

Comment: I tryed it in flash cs5.5 and in flashdevelop. Everything works for me. Try to create new folder in root of c drive and transfer your project.fla, AvoiderGame.as & Enemy.as to it and run.